# Fix gap that appears on an LI element when using :after

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWUTX/

These are the styles used:

```
.box { position: relative; display:inline-block;}
.box:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: green;
    content: '';
    bottom:-10px;
    left:0;
}
```

I get a small **5px** gap when using the style on an **li** element, but not on a **div** tag.

If I specify f`ont-size: 0px`, the gap goes away. But then all the text within the `li` disappears.

As the font size of the `li` increases, the gap widens.

Is there a style to get rid of this gap, without any hard coding of font sizes?

Fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/EWUTX/

Thanks

PS: I'm actually building a CSS framework internally where users can specify a status (using classes) like "`started`", "`not-started`", etc.

When used, the element should display a small bar below with different colors. Users can use this class on any element.

Comment: How does your html look, do you use .box on your li's?

Comment: @Razz, Please see http://jsfiddle.net/EWUTX/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That gap is part of the line height reserved characters like 'p' letter.
You will get the same gap if you don't set a height to your div.  If you want to remove that from an inline element like an img you can set the vertical-align to the bottom:

```
.box img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DhTzp/

Answer (score 1):

Its the image that crates the whitespace;

```
img{ display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks Razz. Your solution works, but it also moves all other elements to the next line.